# Limit Number of Sticky Posts to Show

Tags: sticky-post

I'm using sticky posts as features posts on home page. I'd like to limit the number of sticky posts to show two the latest two. I found this code, but it makes only on latest sticky post to show.

I'd appreciate your help.

```
        <?php
            /* Get all sticky posts */
            $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

            /* Sort the stickies with the newest ones at the top */
            rsort( $sticky );

            /* Get the 2 newest stickies (change 2 for a different number) */
            $sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 2 );

            /* Query sticky posts */
            query_posts( array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'caller_get_posts' => 1 ) );
        ?>
```

Comment: What is `var_dump($sticky;` after the `array_slice`?

Comment: I don't see 'var_dump($sticky;' after 'array_slice'

Comment: Of course you don't see it. You need to _add that code_ and then post the output as an [edit] to the question.

Comment: @Jaeeun Lee, s_ha_dum means put `var_dump($sticky);` right after the line `$sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 2 );`, then save, and then tell what was the displayed value.

Comment: I solved it thanks to this thread [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67557/schedule-sticky-posts?rq=1)